# Problem 2. in Stein & Shakarachi (Dirichlet kernel violates the second property of good kernels)

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

If $$ D = \sum_{k=-N}^{N}e^{ik\theta} = \frac{\sin((N + \frac{1}{2})\theta)}{\sin(\theta/2)} $$I want to show that $$|D_{N}(\theta)|\geq c \frac{\sin((N + \frac{1}{2})\theta)}{|\theta|}$$Could anyone give me a hint? I am stucked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it suffices to show that $| \theta | > c\sin (\frac{\theta}2)$? Do you know how to show $x \ge \sin x$ based on calculus? (take derivative of $f(x) = x - \sin x$ etc.)

Comment: yes, I know how to prove that $x \geq sin x $ so I know that $|sin (\theta/2)| \leq |\theta/2|$  so  $ c=2$?

Comment: @weakmathematician $c$ could take other values too. For example $c = 1$.

Comment: yes you are right.